# Pushing OR Polling

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, wcf

I have a SL client and a WCF service. The client polls the WCF every 4 seconds and I have almost 100 clients at a time.

The web server is an entry level server with 512 MB RAM.

I want to know, if polling is dependent on the server configuration, if I increase the server configuration will the polling for clients work better?

And second, would pushing (duplex) be better than polling? I have got some mixed response from the blogs I have been reading.

Moreover, what are the best practices in optimizing polling for quicker response at the client? My application needs real-time data

Thanks

Comment: What problem are you seeing?  Is the WCF service not responding within a reasonable amount of time?  Is 4 seconds (+ response time) not "real-time" enough?

Comment: Problem - lets talk about 100 clients. Everyone polls after 4 seconds interval. Now, lets take a random poll_no - the clients are supposed to receive some data. Some of my clients receive it and some don't. Next poll, some other clients receive and a different set don't!

Comment: What does the WCF service do?  Is it computationally intensive or IO-bound (or otherwise long-running?)  Does it call out to a database or do something out-of-process?  It sounds like you have a problem within your service, whether it be that the service is overloaded or otherwise failing; polling by itself is not a problem.  If you run 10 clients against the service, do they all get a response every time?

Comment: WCF does computational service, no database communication. The WCF sends out XML as string to the clients. With less number of clients, it works well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess would be that you have some kind of **race condition** that is showing up only with a larger number of clients.  What concurrency and instancing modes are you using for your WCF service?  (See MSDN: WCF Sessions, Instancing, and Concurrency at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731193.aspx)

If you're "losing" responses the first thing I would do is start **logging or tracing** what's happening at the server.  For instance, when a client "doesn't see" a response, is the server ever getting a request?  (If so, what happens to it, etc etc.)

I would also keep an eye on **memory usage** -- you don't say what OS you're using, but 512 MB is awfully skinny these days.  If you ever get into a swap-to-disk situation, it's clearly not going to be a good thing.

Lastly, assuming that your service is CPU-bound (i.e. no heavy database & filesystem calls), the best way to **raise your throughput** is probably to reduce the message payload (wire size), use the most performant bindings (i.e. if client is .NET and you control it, NetTcp binding is much faster than HTTP), and, of course, multithread your service.  IMHO, with the info you've provided -- and all other things equal -- polling is probably fine and pushing might just make things more complex.  If it's important, you really want to bring a true engineering approach to the problem and identify/measure your bottlenecks.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for that explanation. I am using Windows OS. My client is a SL client, so I doubt if I have any flexibility on the bindings. Do you think, increasing the RAM would bring in better performance?

Comment: "Windows OS" narrows it down to about a dozen choices... ;-)  2000? 2003? XP? Win 7?   You're going to have to look at the task manager or performance counters to see how much memory is being used.  There are plenty of resources around to help you with that.  

SilverLight is a MS technology, so you may have options when it comes to the bindings -- depends on how the client dev team resolves your WCF service endpoints (generated proxy -- harder to change bindings, or configuration file--easy to change).  

But you really need to first fix the dropped responses, then figure out your bottleneck.

Comment: its server '03. Well, ok. I will check the task managers. Specifically, can I monitor per-thread performance on the server?

Comment: With a reasonably modern OS like 2003, you can measure most aspects of your process.  Did you figure out the instancing and concurrency settings for your WCF service?  That may affect performance, as well as your options for improving it.

Comment: Yea I checked those in the link you put up. Were helpful!

Answer (score 1):

"Push" notifications generally have a lower network overhead, since no traffic is sent when there's nothing to communicate. But "pull" notifications often have a lower application overhead, since you don't have to maintain state when the client is just idling waiting for a notification.

Push notifications also tend to be "faster", since clients are notified immediately when the event happens rather than waiting for the next polling interval. But pull notifications are more flexible -- you can use just about any server or protocol you want, and you can double your client capacity just by doubling your polling wait interval.

Comment: I've been wondering about this sort of thing. Do you know of any links to discussion of the advantages/disadvantages of each?